# Trying to pull new SQL objects between dates from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that pulls the information from the sys tables to produce a list of the new objects that have been created in our environment.  What I need to do is the last part of the query needs to be able to look at another table and pull the 3 most current records and use the date from those records to show only the objects that have been created since those 3 dates.  In my testing I keep running into "Subquery returned more than 1 value"  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I am currently running SQL 2008 R2.
The query runs now as is, but only pulls the most recent date, I need it to pull everything from the last 3 dates.

```
SELECT
    a.name AS ObjectName, b.name AS ParameterName, c.name AS DataType,
    b.isnullable AS [Allow Nulls?], a.crdate AS CreateDate,
    CASE WHEN d .name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [PKey?],
    CASE WHEN e.parent_object_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [FKey?],
    CASE WHEN e.parent_object_id IS NULL THEN '-' ELSE g.name END AS [Ref Table],
    CASE WHEN h.value IS NULL THEN '-' ELSE h.value END AS Description, 
    c.length AS FieldSize, a.replinfo AS IsReplicated, 
    CASE a.xtype WHEN 'V' THEN 'View' WHEN 'P' THEN 'StoredProcedure' WHEN 'FN' THEN 'ScalarFunction' WHEN 'F' THEN 'ForeignKey' WHEN 'U' THEN 'Table' WHEN
                      'TR' THEN 'Trigger' WHEN 'TT' THEN 'TableType' WHEN 'PK' THEN 'PrimaryKey' END AS ObjectType
FROM
    sys.sysobjects AS a
    INNER JOIN sys.syscolumns AS b ON a.id = b.id
    INNER JOIN sys.systypes AS c ON b.xtype = c.xtype
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT so.id, sc.colid, sc.name
        FROM
            sys.syscolumns AS sc
            INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects AS so ON so.id = sc.id
            INNER JOIN sys.sysindexkeys AS si ON so.id = si.id AND sc.colid = si.colid
        WHERE (si.indid = 1)) AS d ON a.id = d.id AND b.colid = d.colid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS e ON a.id = e.parent_object_id AND b.colid = e.parent_column_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects AS g ON e.referenced_object_id = g.object_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS h ON a.id = h.major_id AND b.colid = h.minor_id
WHERE        (a.type = 'U' OR
                     a.type = 'V' OR
                     a.type = 'F' OR
                     a.type = 'PK' OR
                     a.type = 'P' OR
                     a.type = 'FN' OR
                     a.type = 'TT' OR
                     a.type = 'TR') AND 
                     (a.crdate >
                         (SELECT        TOP (1) DeployDate
                           FROM            OtherTable.dbo.Tracking 
                           ORDER BY DeployDate DESC))
ORDER BY CreateDate DESC
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: The query as written runs. [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77e0e/1/0) . When does the issue occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the minimum of the last 3 dates in the tracking table.

If so, you could do something like this...

```
(a.crdate >
      (SELECT        Min(topthree.DeployDate)
       FROM         (select Top 3 DeployDate
                     From dbo.Tracking 
                     ORDER BY DeployDate DESC
                    ) as topthree   
       )
)
```